# Python - writing a loop output to a file

Tags: python

I am able to print this in the format I want, how would I write this to a file?
    import json

```
#myfile = open('us-west-2-offering-script.txt', 'w')

with open('Pricing_Json_Cli.json', 'r') as f:
    rawData = json.load(f)

for each in rawData['ReservedInstancesOfferings']:
    print('PDX', ','
          , each['InstanceType'], ','
          , each['InstanceTenancy'], ','
          , each['ProductDescription'], ','
          , each['OfferingType'], ','
          , each['Duration'], ','
          , each['ReservedInstancesOfferingId'], ','
          , each['FixedPrice'], ',', end=''
          )
    if not each['RecurringCharges']:
        print("0.0")
    else:
        print(each['RecurringCharges'][0].get('Amount'))
```

## myfile.close()

Answer (score 2):

While you can define an output stream for the `print()` function, a more straight-forward way is to just use `file_stream.write()` instead:

```
with open("output_file", "w") as f:  # open output_file for writing
    for each in rawData['ReservedInstancesOfferings']:
        # join all elements by a comma and write to the file
        f.write(",".join(
            map(str, ("PDX",
                      each['InstanceType'],
                      each['InstanceTenancy'],
                      each['ProductDescription'],
                      each['OfferingType'],
                      each['Duration'],
                      each['ReservedInstancesOfferingId'],
                      each['FixedPrice'],
                      "0.0" if not each['RecurringCharges']
                      else each['RecurringCharges'][0].get('Amount')))
        ))
        f.write("\n")  # write a new line at the end
```

Comment: Only real difference is whether you get newline at the end for free.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I am a step closer, but this errors out because ['RecurringCharges'][0].get('Amount') is an int and join looks for strings.

I have tried to just wrap the entire thing in str() but it does not work. Thoughts?

Comment: That is what I tried, and it makes sense to me but still getting the error:

TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, int found .. for accuracy I updated my source code to show everything.

Comment: @Ka_Fari - that means that another piece of your data is not a string. Check the update, it ensures that all parameters are turned into strings first.

Comment: You're a god. Bless your soul.